# How to return queryselector and queryselectorall in one function?

Tags: javascript

I am using functions `get()` and `getall()` to shorten query selector and query selector all.

```js
const get = (target) => {document.querySelector(target)}
const getAll = (target) => {document.querySelectorAll(target)};
```

I wanted to fix this code as a function, so I was going to examine the element and create a function `get()` that `return querySelectorAll` if there are multiple elements of the same element and `return querySelector` if not.

So I made the code written below.

```js
 const get = (target) => {
    if (NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(target)) {
      return document.querySelectorAll(target)
    } else {
      return document.querySelector(target)
    }
  }

  console.log(get('div'));
```

```js
const get = (target) => {
    if(target, target.length > 1) {
      return document.querySelectorAll(target);
    }else{
      return document.querySelector(target)
    }
  }
```

```js
  const get = (target) => {
    if(typeof(target) == 'object') {
      return document.querySelectorAll(target);
    }else{
      return document.querySelector(target)
    }
  }
```

However, all of the above codes do not work.
Type of target is string when entering the function.

Comment: You may also want to consider passing in a "context" which defaults to `document`: `function get(selector, context = document) {` in case you want to use another element instead of `document` to perform the query on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check the length of the result of `document.querySelectorAll`.

```js
const get = (target) => {
    const els = document.querySelectorAll(target);
    return els.length > 1 ? els : els[0];
}
```

Comment: Everything works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would still stick with what you have as it makes more sense and it it's predictable.

If you have

```
const get = (target) => document.querySelector(target);
const getAll = (target) => document.querySelectorAll(target);
```

You know what to expect from each of them, you can check for a `Node` or a `null` if you used `get`, or you can use `getAll` and expect an array, whether it's empty or not.

Now if you want to stick with your decision, your implementation would look like this:

```js
const get = (target) => {
  if (target && target.trim().length > 1) {
    const rs = document.querySelectorAll(target);
    if (rs.length === 1) {
      return rs[0];
    } else {
      if (rs.length) {
        return rs
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This would check that `target` is not empty, and it's not just empty spaces, then it checks if it's one element, or multiple if not it returns `null`

Comment: That's a wonderful answer. Thank you.